# Ratio of 2D histograms in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, histogram2d

I have two sets of data from which I am separately plotting 2D histograms using matplotlib's hist2d() as in http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hist2d_log_demo.html.
Now I would like to have the ratio of these two 2D histograms (i.e. the ratio of the frequency). How can I achieve this in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Internally](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py) `hist2d` uses [`numpy.histogram2d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html). Thus you can compute both histograms using this function, compute the ratio and then plot it using `pcolormesh`, `imshow` or similar.

```
h1, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x1, y1, bins=bins)
h2, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x2, y2, bins=bins)
h = h1 / h2
pc = ax.pcolorfast(xedges, yedges, h.T)
```